# ACL for two users on the same object

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I need to set read and write access for two users on the same object. I could make a working solution, but I'm not sure that it's the nicest or correct way to do that. After I run the above lines, in the ACL column of the data browser I get two objectID what belongs to the two user that I want to be able to edit the object. So is it good? Or is there any room for improvement?

```
PFACL *objACL = [PFACL ACL];

[objACL setReadAccess:YES forUser:userB];
[objACL setWriteAccess:YES forUser:userB];

[objACL setReadAccess:YES forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[objACL setWriteAccess:YES forUser:[PFUser currentUser]];

PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"ClassName"];
object.ACL = objACL

[object saveInBackground];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the users for each object are different then this is the appropriate way, otherwise you can assign a role to these two users and use [setReadAccess:forRole](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFACL.html#//api/name/setReadAccess:forRole:)